# Derivatives: prove there is no horizontal tangent line to graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

Equation: $-3xy + x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Demonstrate that there is no horizontal tangent using inverse variation.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What are you familiar with?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/taking-derivatives-calc/implicit-differentiation-intro-calc/v/implicit-differentiation-1).

Comment: Do you mean $ z=f(x,y)=x^2-3xy+y^2 $ ? Then you have horizontal tangent at (0,0). If you meant that the given expression is y=f(x) then differentiate implicitly as already suggested. Result should immediately follow.

Comment: @Avi The point $\;(0,0)\;$ is neither on the function's graph nor in the (implicit) derivative's domain.

Comment: Yes DonAntonio , I forgot to check the last bit! So yes, the claim stands verified irrespective of the fact whether the expression is a function of 1 variable or 2 .

Comment: Thank you @DonAntonio and everyone else! You solved my problem! I was overlooking that I could come up with the y = 2/3x and return to the original equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate implicitly:

$$2x-3y-3xy'+2yy'=0\implies(2y-3x)y'=3y-2x\implies y'=\frac{3y-2x}{2y-3x}$$

Thus, the only point where the derivative is *defined* and equals zero is when $\;3y-2x=0\;,\;\;(x,y)\in\text{ Dom}\,(f)\;$ , but then

$$y=\frac23x\implies f\left(x,\,\frac23x\right)=x^2-2x^2+\frac49x^2=1\iff-\frac59x^2=1$$

and this last equality is impossible (in the real number, of course), thus $\;y'\neq0\;$ for all points where it is defined.

Comment: You mean, of course, that "$y'\ne 0$ for all points where it is defined".

Comment: @user247327 Yes, of course. Thanks.