# Implicit differentiation : two or four tangents?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

> **My Question is**: The equation of a curve is $$ x ^ 2 - 2 x y + 2 y ^ 2 = 4 $$ Find the coordinates of each point on the curve at which the tangent is parallel to the $ x $-axis.

So I established that $$ \frac { \mathop { \sf d } y } { \mathop { \sf d } x } = 0 \implies y = x $$ Therefore $ x = \pm 2 $ by subbing $ x = y $ in to the original equation. The problem I'm having is that if I sub $ x = \pm 2 $ in to the original equation I get $ 4 $ coordinates. But when I sub it in to $ \frac { \mathop { \sf d } y } { \mathop { \sf d } x } $ I get $ 2 $ coordinates?

The correct answer is $ ( 2 , 2 ) $ and $ ( 2 , - 2 ) $ which is from subbing $ x $ in to $ \frac { \mathop { \sf d } y } { \mathop { \sf d } x } = 0 $.

Why isn't subbing $ x $ in to the original equation correct?

Answer (score 1):

Subbing $x$ into the original equation isn't wrong, it's just not enough.  This is because $x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2 = 4$ does not express $y$ as a function of $x$.

With implicit functions, it's not enough to just plug the $x$-coordinates back into the original function, because that doesn't tell you which $x$- and $y$-coordinates correspond to points with the desired slope.  This is why you also need to evaluate $dy/dx$ at the points you find.  This is not an issue with *explicit* functions because each $x$-coordinate corresponds to at most one $y$-coordinate.

Another way of looking at it:  For this problem, you've found that $dy/dx = 0$ implies $x = \pm 2$.  This is correct.  But this does *not* mean that $x= \pm 2$ implies $dy/dx = 0$.  And again, this is not an issue with explicit functions because for explicit functions it isn't possible for one $x$-coordinate to correspond to more than one point on the graph (and therefore potentially more than one derivative or slope).

Comment: But the condition $x = y$ comes from setting $y'=0$ and using this condition it is possible to get the results

Comment: @RafaelWagner, indeed, that's why I said it isn't wrong, it's just not enough.

Comment: @Destudent, glad to help!

Comment: @tilper  totally (+1), just pointed to him.

Answer (score 0):

### The Points

See that

$$x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2 = 4 \implies (x - y)^2 = 2^2 - y^2 = (2-y)(2+y)$$

So we have that

> $$(x - y)^2 = (2-y)(2+y)$$

If we differentiate the equation we get that, using the notation $y' := \mathrm dy/\mathrm d x$

$$2x - 2y - 2xy' + 4yy' = 0 \implies y' = \frac{y - x}{2y - x}$$

Setting $y' = 0$ implies that $y = x$ and if you use this result in the above equation you'll find

$$(2-y)(2+y) = 0$$

So you must have that $y = 2$ or $y = -2$ then you get the results $(2,2)$ and $(-2,-2)$ and as @tilper pointed out

$$y'(2,2) = y'(-2,-2) = 0$$

note that $y'(2,-2) = 4/6 \neq 0$ so in this point you do not get the tangent parallel.

### These are the only points?

**Yes**. To find horizontal tangents we have to find points where $y'= 0$. So we have in this case that the *only* points were the derivative is equal to zero are the points where

$$y = x \hspace{0.3cm} \text{for points }(x,y)\in \text{Dom}(f)$$

where $f(x,y) = x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2$. We are looking for the curve $f(x,y)=4$ then the points that have $x = y$ will be such that pointed out above. These are the *only* solutions to this curve so they are the only points. By the definition the tangent is horizontal when the point is [stationary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StationaryPoint.html) and they occur only when the derivative is zero. It is important that the derivative $y'$ is well defined, e.g., in the points $2y = x$ the derivative is not defined.

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943767/derivatives-prove-there-is-no-horizontal-tangent-line-to-graph) where the answer given is such that, to demonstrate that there is no horizontal tangent,  the author proves that $y'\neq 0$ for all points in the domain.

Comment: So the only valid point that answers the question is (2,2)? The book's answer still included (2,-2). Thanks.

Comment: @Destudent if the derivative $y' \neq 0$ then in this point the tangent is not parallel so $(2,-2)$ is not an answer.

Comment: @Destudent, $(-2,-2)$ is also an answer.  $(2,2)$ and $(-2, -2)$ are the only answers.  If the book says $(2,-2)$ is an answer then that's most likely a typo.